# Initialising CoreData in AppleScript-objc

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, core-data, applescript-objc

I'm trying to write and read from CoreData on OSX, combinig cocoa classes with applescript-objc.
I wrote methods to handle my CoreData as in tutorial ([youtube, Cocoa Tutorial: Core Data Introduction in iOS and Mac OS Programming Part 2](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=imGTX_YJMa8)) <- those are cocoa classes in my project

I have a class called CoreDataHelper that defines methods to manipulate Core Data. Here are some of them:

```
+(NSManagedObjectContext *) managedObjectContext{
    NSError*error;
    [[NSFileManager defaultManager] createDirectoryAtPath:[CoreDataHelper directoryForDatabaseFilename] withIntermediateDirectories:YES attributes:nil error:&error];

    if(error){
        NSLog(@"%@", [error localizedDescription]);
        return nil;
    }

    NSString* path = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@",[CoreDataHelper directoryForDatabaseFilename],[CoreDataHelper databaseFilename]];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
    NSManagedObjectModel* managedModel = [NSManagedObjectModel mergedModelFromBundles:nil];
    NSPersistentStoreCoordinator* storeCordinator = [[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator alloc] initWithManagedObjectModel:managedModel];

    if(![storeCordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType configuration:nil URL:url options:nil error:&error]){
        NSLog(@"%@",[error localizedDescription]);
        return nil;
    }

    NSManagedObjectContext* managedObjectContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSMainQueueConcurrencyType];

    return managedObjectContext;
}


+(id)insertManagedObjectOfClass:(Class) aClass inManagedObjectContext:(NSManagedObjectContext *)managedObjectContext{
    NSManagedObject* managedObject = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:NSStringFromClass(aClass) inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];

    return managedObject;
}
```

I'm using .xcdatamodeld for my Model.
I have 2 entities in it with classes for each one of them:

1. Tab
2. Service

Tab.h looks like this

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <CoreData/CoreData.h>

@class Service;

NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_BEGIN

@interface Tab : NSManagedObject

// Insert code here to declare functionality of your managed object subclass

@end

NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_END

#import "Tab+CoreDataProperties.h"
```

and Tab.m looks like this:

```
#import "Tab.h"
#import "Service.h"

@implementation Tab

// Insert code here to add functionality to your managed object subclass

@end
```

Tab+CoreDataProperties.h:

```
 #import "Tab.h"

    NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_BEGIN

    @interface Tab (CoreDataProperties)

    @property (nullable, nonatomic, retain) NSString *nZakladka;
    @property (nullable, nonatomic, retain) NSString *uZakladka;
    @property (nullable, nonatomic, retain) Service *podstronaSerwisu;

    @end

    NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_END
```

Tab+CoreDataProperties.m:
    #import "Tab+CoreDataProperties.h"

```
@implementation Tab (CoreDataProperties)

@dynamic nZakladka;
@dynamic uZakladka;
@dynamic podstronaSerwisu;

@end
```

Now, my AppDelegate.applescript looks like this

```
...

property CoreDataHelper: class "CoreDataHelper"
property cService: class "Service"
property cTab: class "Tab"

script AppDelegate

  on applicationWillFinishLaunching_(aNotification)

    set theContext to CoreDataHelper's managedObjectContext() 
    set ccTab to cTab's alloc()'s init()

    //the one below cause an error "CoreData: error: Failed to call designated initializer on NSManagedObject class 'Tab'"
    set theTab to CoreDataHelper's insertManagedObjectOfClass_inManagedObjectContext_(ccTab, theContext)

  end applicationWillFinishLaunching_

...

end Script
```

When I run whole thing I got an error message posted in a commented line in AppleScriptObjC code. The method that is causing an error is  `NSManagedObject* managedObject = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:NSStringFromClass(aClass) inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];`
What is the problem?

Comment: Try `insertManagedObjectOfClass_inManagedObjectContext_(cTab, theContext)`. class `cTab` instead of instance `ccTab`.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Unfortunately, `cTab` gives me this error: `+entityForName: nil is not a legal NSPersistentStoreCoordinator for searching for entity name 'Tab' (error -10000)`

Comment: Which error do you get when you use `ccTab`?

Comment: From `ccTab` I get error: `CoreData: error: Failed to call designated initializer on NSManagedObject class 'Tab'`

Comment: I think it is easier to supply the entity name instead of a class. `insertNewObjectForEntityForName` wants a string.

Comment: You mean like this: `set theTab to CoreDataHelper's insertManagedObjectOfClass_inManagedObjectContext_("Tab", theContext)`. It also produce an error. Without message, just `(lldb)`. I don't have any idea what is going wrong.

Comment: Did you also change `[NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:NSStringFromClass(aClass)` to `[NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:aClass`?

Comment: Oh, I haven't. Now it gives me this error on run: `+entityForName: nil is not a legal NSPersistentStoreCoordinator for searching for entity name 'Tab' (error -10000)`. Also after changing the line you point out it shows me the warning on aClass that `Incompatible pointer types sending 'Class' to paramater of type 'NSString * _Nonnull'`